# Finish all activities except one

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

When i use this method, i go back to the login page, but I can still click the return button and it returns me to the previous activity. why doesn't it close other activities?

```
public void restartApplication() {
        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);   
    }
```

Is there a way to finish all activities except the login activity? or restart the whole app?

Answer (score 3):

I think because of package manager, the activity is starting on a new history stack.

Try using activity name instead of getting from package manager.
Eg.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `finish();` after `startActivity(i);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); inplace of intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        yourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(intent);
```